# Tooltip not working when img is append to div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am appending images to a div with tooltip, but the tooltip is not working for the images in the div. I have one static image outside the div and for this the tooltip is working.

below is an except from the jquery function:

```
success: function (result) {
  if (result != null) {
    var MyPics = result.MyIctures;
    $.each(MyPics, function (index, value) {
      var im = (MyPics[index].FILE_PATH);
      console.log(MyPics[index].file_date);
      var img = $("<img />");
      img.attr("id",""+ MyPics[index].file_path+"");
      img.attr("style", "height:100px;width: 100px");
      img.attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      img.attr("data-html", "true");
      img.attr("data-placement", "top");
      img.attr("title", "<em>Title:" + MyPics[index].file_name + "</em> <hr> <b></b>");
     img.addClass("img_preview");
     img.attr("src", im);
     $("#mypics").append(img);
     // console.log(im);
     //   
     }
   )
  }
}
```

The tooltip for this img works but not the ones append to the div.

```
<img id="bing_img_dessc" class="img_preview" style="height:50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="<em>sss</em> <hr> <b>sss</b>" src="~/Resources/Images/login-user-icon.png">
```

Any suggestions will help. Thnaks.

Comment: You probably need to instantiate the tooltip library on the new elements. Which tooltip library are you using, and how do you call it when the page loads?

Comment: I have instantiated the tooltips on the page with `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` and it is loaded when document is ready

Comment: You need to do the same when appending the new images. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you only call `tooltip()` when the page loads, so only the elements which existed in the DOM at that point will show the tooltip on hover. To fix this you need to also call `tooltip()` when you add the new images:

```js
success: function(result) {
  if (!result)
    return;

  var images = result.MyIctures.map(function(image) {
    return $('<img />', {
      'id': image.file_path,
      'data': {
        'toggle': 'tooltip',
        'html': 'true',
        'placement': 'top'
      },
      'title': '<em>Title:' + image.file_name + '</em><hr>',
      'class': 'img_preview',
      'src': image.FILE_PATH
    });
  });

  $("#mypics").append(images).find('.img_preview').tooltip();
}
```

Note that I tidied up the logic to make it a little more succinct by using `map()` to build an array of jQuery objects to append only once.

Also note that you're using both a `FILE_PATH` and `file_path` property; make sure this is correct as JS is case-sensitive. `MyIctures` should probably also be `MyPictures`

Comment: I tried it but the tooltip is still not working for me

Comment: I don't see errors. But I see that in the generated `html img tag` it is not showing the `data` attributres